# How to protect credentials in an Android application

Tags: android, security, encryption, obfuscation

I am keen to achieve a high level of security for credentials that are used to connect to external services, such as APIs that are billed.

If I store credentials in a C library as a .so (binary) and access them using JNI with the application signing key, does that sound like sufficient protection?

I'm trying to gauge the ease with which an attacker might be able to decompile or otherwise reverse engineer in order to access the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Many developers struggle with the security concepts. Many try to hide the passwords somewhere in the app under different names "so nobody can find them", others try to compile them or encrypt them into the app, etc... We really need to understand that hiding is **not** security.

If you compile your password into your app, a hacker can easily get it from there. Reverse engineering is not difficult. If your app is popular or it makes it worth it for hackers to go through the efforts to find the password in the binary, I can assure you that they will find it.

Some developers will tell you to encrypt the password before you compile it to the binary. Great, now you will have to save the encryption key somewhere, don't you? Where? Compile it into the app, and you're back to square one.

You will need to store your secrets (either the password itself, or the encryption key if the password was encrypted) outside your app in a way that is not reachable by the hacker. So the real issue that you need to think about is: Where to store your secrets so the app can read it, but the hacker cannot?

How to achieve that really depends on your design. For example, if the billed API is accessed by your users who you securely authenticate, then you can use the user's credentials to securely access the API. This way, no need for global credentials to access the API.

To illustrate that in an example: I log in to your app using my credentials (via HTTPS), then I choose a feature that needs to access the billed API. Your app sends an HTTPS request to the API and include my credentials in the request (header, URL, or body, whatever you like as they're all secured by HTTPS). The API receives the request, validates my credentials (in a similar way to the login process) and returns the results to the app (or returns an "access denied" error if the credentials are wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are in your app, then a motivated hacker can find them...  putting them into a C++ library would probably make it slightly harder though.